# nLog logging session variables always empty

Tags: c#, session, logging, nlog, asp.net-core-2.2

I'm using nLog in one of our web applications. It works perfectly for most of the variables we're logging but the only one I cannot get to work for the live of me is the

**${aspnet-session:variable=VarX}**

This will always result in an empty string, however in the web application VarX is accessible in the session and has a value.

I lost the link(s), but I know/read it's important to have the order of middleware correct in "Startup.cs" in both ConfigureServices and Configure.

In the first the "AddSession" call needs to be after the "AddMvc" call, in the lather it's the other way around (from what I'v read).
I have set nLog's internal log to "trace" and I can see the value is empty.

There's nothing logged otherwise in nLog's internal log.

Today I have updated NLog.Web.AspNetCore to 4.8.4. Before it was writing entries in the log that  "Session Feature not configured". Now it doesn't do that anymore.
The changelog for the NLog.Web.AspNetCore 4.8.4 mentions that it improved this behavior but we still cannot retrieve session variables in the nLog logger.

```xml
    <target xsi:type="Database"
            name="database"
            dbProvider="sqlserver"
            connectionString="server=server;database=db;Integrated Security=False;User ID=user;Password=pw;multipleactiveresultsets=True"
            keepConnection="false"
            commandType="text">
      <commandText>
        INSERT INTO table (SessionVarX)
        VALUES (@SessionVarX);
      </commandText>
      <parameter name="@SessionVarX" layout="${aspnet-session:variable=SessionVarX}"/>
    </target>
```

```cs
private static readonly LoggerFactory _loggerFactory = new LoggerFactory(new[] { new NLogLoggerProvider() });

       public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.Strict;
                options.Secure = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
            });

            services.AddSingleton(Configuration);
            services.AddDbContextPool<DBContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("string")).
                ConfigureWarnings(warnings => warnings.
                    Ignore(new EventId[] { CoreEventId.IncludeIgnoredWarning, RelationalEventId.BoolWithDefaultWarning, RelationalEventId.QueryClientEvaluationWarning })

                ).
                EnableDetailedErrors().
                UseLoggerFactory(_loggerFactory)
            );
            services.AddAntiforgery();
            services.AddMemoryCache();

            services.AddHsts(options =>
            {
                options.Preload = options.IncludeSubDomains = true;
                options.MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromDays(365);
            });

            services.AddMvc(config => { config.Filters.Add(new AuthenticationFilter()); }).
                SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2).
                AddJsonOptions(x => x.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore).
                AddSessionStateTempDataProvider();

            services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

            services.AddSession(options =>
            {
                options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(Configuration.Get<int>("SessionTimeoutInMinutes"));
                options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
                options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
                options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            });

       public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            if (CurrentEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error/Exception");
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Error", "?code={0}");
            app.UseSession();
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
            {
                OnPrepareResponse = ctx =>
                {
                    //Cache static files for a week
                    ctx.Context.Response.Headers[Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.HeaderNames.CacheControl] = "public,max-age=604800";
                }
            });

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "areas",
                    template: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
                );
            });
        }
```

Expected result is that the SessionVarX gets logged, actual result is an empty string. **So records do get created (there's more being logged), however the session variables are always empty**.
Currently there's no error logged in nLog's internal log. Previously that log showed "Session Feature not configured".

Any help would be greatly appreciated! It could well be that this feature is still being ironed out (looking at the nLog issuetracker) but since it's there already for some time and properly documented, I hope there's something we can do to get it to work.

Comment: The database is an mdf file and the log file is ldf.   Are the datetime of these files getting updated?  If you open SQL Server Management studio and right click on the database it will show the location of where the files are located.

Comment: The records get inserted, that's not the problem.
The example I posted is abbreviated and removed sensitive info but there's more being logged than just SessionVarX. Records get created, however the SessionVarX is just being added as empty.

Comment: See if this helps : https://www.sqlshack.com/creating-a-sql-server-audit-using-sql-server-extended-events-and-triggers/

Comment: Try to check the internal log, it will tell you why it's empty: See https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Internal-logging

Comment: Already did that and it doesn't mention anything. It's set to trace and I can see it's being inserted as empty. But nothing else. Before (older versions) it said that the session feature isn't available, with the latest it doesn't do that anymore. This is definitely not the case since I have my own Middleware reading out session variables. So I think that for some reason it can't access the session but why is unclear.

Comment: Hi Jos, were you able to figure it out? I am having the exact same problem. I'm using Core 3.1. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @dailyUnknown nope never resolved. I believe it not to be possible by the way things are setup. See here for a question I asked on Github;
https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/3511